# update FragmentPageAdapter with listfragment

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-fragments

I want Update/refresh the pages of FragmentPageAdapter.
In each page I have a custom ListView With checkbox, When I check one, I want refresh the page and This selection pass to other page.

The one page show the list with checkbox checked and the other list show a checkbox not checked

The arrayAdapter I stuffed with BBDD data

I've been looking around here but can not find a clear solution .. sorry

the code is:

Class with FragmentPageAdapter:

```
class GoogleMusicAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public GoogleMusicAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        postab = position;
        return FragmentListaPendiente.init(position);

    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length].toUpperCase();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return CONTENT.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

}
```

Class on Implement FragmentPageAdapter:

```
public class MyListaCompra extends SherlockFragment  {

View gv;
int postab = 0;
private static String[] CONTENT;

public static Intent newInstance(Activity activity,int pos) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, MyListaCompra.class);
    return intent;
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    CONTENT = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabCompra);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    Log.i("Truiton FragmentList", "ON CREATE O!");
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Fragment newContent = null;
    SwipeMenuListFragment f = new SwipeMenuListFragment();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_new:
        //newContent = new añadirCompra();
        Intent t = new Intent(getActivity(),DetallesListaCompra.class);
        getActivity().startActivityForResult(t, 0);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    gv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inicio,container, false);
    FragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new GoogleMusicAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) gv.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    TabPageIndicator indicator = (TabPageIndicator) gv.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    indicator.setViewPager(pager);

    return gv;
}

}
```

And Pages code

```
    int fragNum;
private static View gv;
adapterCompra adapter;
private boolean result;
List<ListaCompra> lista = new ArrayList<ListaCompra>();


public static FragmentListaPendiente init(int val) {
    FragmentListaPendiente truitonList = new FragmentListaPendiente();

    // Supply val input as an argument.
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("val", val);
    truitonList.setArguments(args);

    return truitonList;
}

 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     fragNum = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("val") : 1;

}
/**
 * The Fragment's UI is a simple text view showing its instance number and
 * an associated list.
 */
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    gv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listframe,null);

    MiBBDD miZappe = new MiBBDD(getActivity(), "zappe", null, 1);

    SQLiteDatabase db =  miZappe.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c1;
    if(fragNum==0)
         c1 = utilsBBDD.ObtenerListasCompraPorHacerBBDDInterna(getActivity());
    else
         c1 = utilsBBDD.ObtenerListasCompraRealizadaBBDDInterna(getActivity());


    miZappe.close();
    if (c1!= null && c1.moveToFirst())
    {

        do {
            ListaCompra listaC = new ListaCompra();
            listaC.setId_lista(c1.getInt(0));
            listaC.setNombreLista(c1.getString(2));
            listaC.setStatus(c1.getInt(3));
            lista.add(listaC);
        } while (c1.moveToNext());


    c1.close();     
    }


    return gv;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    adapter = new adapterCompra(getActivity());
    for(int i=0;i<lista.size();i++){
        adapter.add(lista.get(i));
    }
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

}

public class adapterCompra extends ArrayAdapter<ListaCompra> {
    CheckBox check;
    public adapterCompra(Context context) {
        super(context, 0);
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.inflate_lista, null);
        }
        final View v = convertView;
        v.setTag(lista.get(position).id_lista);
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.NombreLista);
        title.setText(getItem(position).getNombreLista());          
        check = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        if(fragNum==1)
            check.setChecked(true);

        final int pos = position;



        check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if(buttonView.isChecked()){
                    AlertChangePurchase((Integer) v.getTag(), 1);       
                }
                else{
                    AlertChangePurchase((Integer) v.getTag(), 0);
                    if(!result)
                        buttonView.setChecked(true);
                    else
                        buttonView.setChecked(false);
                }

            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    public void AlertChangePurchase(final int id_compra,int status){

         AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(gv.getContext());

            // Setting Dialog Title
            alertDialog.setTitle("COMPRA");
            result = true;
            if(status==0){
                alertDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.AlertDeschekedCompra));
                conditionsAlert(alertDialog, id_compra, status);

            }
            else{
                 // Setting Dialog Message
                alertDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.AlertChekedCompra));
                conditionsAlert(alertDialog, id_compra, status);
            }
            alertDialog.show();

    }

    public void conditionsAlert( AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog,final int id_compra,final int status){
        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                MiBBDD miZappe = new MiBBDD(getActivity(), "zappe", null, 1);
                utilsBBDD.CambiarStadoCompra(getActivity(), id_compra, status);
                miZappe.close();

            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
            if(status==0)
                result = false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Sorry for my english

Thanks for help

Comment: if you just want to have a listview with check boxes then use a PreferencesFragment and then create an xml file for that , that contains checkbox preferences and that would save them whit sharedpreferences.

Comment: no, the listview is generated dinamically... i don't want prefrenceFragment... I want update list when the checkbox change, and the list element change to the other page

Comment: so you need to save them with shared preferences

Comment: no,I think that you don't understand me... I have two page with a listview... my idea is that I deschecked an element of the list, the list will be updated and this ad will go away element to go to another page

Answer (score 0):

You'll want your fragment with the checkboxes to have a  Listener interface it calls through to notify of checkbox changes. Your parent activity implements this listener and receives the messages. The activity then performs the appropriate action on the other fragments.

See this for reference:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity